# SyntaxError: 'return' outside function generated in the comment

Tags: python

```
myfile=open("output_log.text", "r")
for file in myfile:
    count = 0
    for word in file:
        if word == "Jenkins":
            count = count + 1
        return word
print(int(word))
```

The coding above generated a syntax error which I mentioned in the title as above. Does anyone can help me to solve this problem? Thanks everyone.

Comment: remove `return word`?

Comment: why we need to remove the "return word"? by the way thanks for your answer.

Comment: since you're not using functions you don't have to return

Comment: `return` is a keyword specific to python functions. Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_return.asp) for a good explanation.

Comment: I need to count the word "jenkins" in the word file. Is my coding correct? Thanks

Comment: The inner loop ends up not over the words in the line but rather over the characters (read codepoints) so the equality is never true as a string of length 1 can never be equal to a string of greater length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OK, you have not defined a function yet. :-)  

####### Beginning of python script #######

def myfunc(myword, myfile):
    # rest of your function code.
    for file in myfile:
        count = 0
        for word in file:
            if word == myword:
                count = count + 1
    return myword, count  

# Now call the function from outside.
# Set myfile and myword variables.
myfile = open(r'c:\python\so\output_log.text', "r")
myword = 'Jenkins'
results = myfunc(myword, myfile)

print(results)
# Example print output.
> ('Jenkins', 4) 

# You are passing myfile and myword as variables in your function call.
# You can changes these later for a different file and a different word.
```

Comment: Actually I need to count the word "jenkins" in the text file. Is my coding correct for counting the word? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jennifer. By the way another problem is encountered, the comment stated that my file path is not correct. Is there anyway to solve this problem since I put the file path in the correct path.

Comment: Ya the other solution work. Thanks for your solution too and lending me a help, I had learnt from your coding too. By the way, may I know the difference between "with" function, "import" function and "from XX as XX" function? I am quite confused about this.

Comment: Ya thanks a lot Jennifer, your explanation about the function of the "import" and other are quite helpful for me. I can understand it well. I have try your coding as well, it's work. Thanks a lot Jennifer.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement should be used within a function/method. You have not defined one therefore the use of `return` is incorrect. You should print the word instead of using return. Also you're opening the file and not closing it. I suggest using the `with` statement.

```
with open("output_log.text", "r") as myfile:
    for file in myfile:
        count = 0
        for word in file:
            if word == "Jenkins":
                count = count + 1
print(int(word))
```

Most likely I assume You're trying to print the number of times `"Jenkins"` shows up in the file. You want to print `count` then. *Also `file` is inappropriately named it should be `line` as you're reading lines of a file not files of a file.* I'd say you're looking to do something like this

```
def count_word_in_file(filename, keyword):
    count = 0
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                if word == keyword:
                    count += 1
    return count

count = count_word_in_file("output_log.text", "Jenkins") 
print(count)
```

**Note** This can be done much more simply using `str.count` method BTW.

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    print(file.read().count("Jenkins"))
```

Comment: I used this code, but there is another problem came out.
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
What means by this error?

Comment: Because word isn't an `int`.

Comment: Before i posted one question on this site I read and did every exercise in Python crash course...

Comment: how about if I want to count the word "jenkins' in the text file? Is my coding correct?

Comment: Thanks Jab. By the way can I know the difference between "with" function, "import" function and "from XX as XX" function? I may confuse about this.

Comment: To learn python basics you should go through a python course. Or just use the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). The [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) is used with [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers). The [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statement is used to include code from other modules. And the `from ... as ...` is included in the `import` docs

Comment: Ok thanks Jab. I will learn more python course from Internet. Thanks for your helping.